# Fetching Scrapy Url regex

Tags: python, scrapy

I've written a spider in Scrapy which is basically doing fine and does exactly what it is supposed to do. but the problem is in the log when i execute the the scrapy crawl

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from ecommerce.items import ArticleItem


class WikiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wiki'
    start_urls = (
    'http://www.wiki.tn/index.php',
    )
    rules= [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\w+\/\d{1,4}\/\d{1,4}\/\d{1,4}\X+']),follow=True,     callback='parse_Article_wiki'),
]

    def parse_Article_wiki(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = ArticleItem()

        print '*******************>> '+response.url
```

But it dosn't work when i execute the spider it shows me :

```
    2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, 
        OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [wiki] INFO: Spider opened
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [wiki] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0     items/min)
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [wiki] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.wiki.tn/index.php> (referer:     None)
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [wiki] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [wiki] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 219,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 13062,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9, 14, 3, 13, 416073),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
        'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
        'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9, 14, 3, 13, 210430)}
2014-07-09 15:03:13+0100 [wiki] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: What's the intention of `\X+` at the end of you `allow` pattern? I do not see it supported in https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. Without it, you should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of what your question is. Guessing, I think that you want to crawl the site, and it is not doing it.

If that is the problem, it can be the regex you are using in your rules definition. What kind of links are you trying to follow?

On the other hand, I also recommend that you use the allowed_domains variable, that in your case would be:

```
allowed_domains = ['wiki.tn']
```